# Is there a more F# idiomatic way for code using TPL?

Tags: f#, apache-kafka

I'm converting the following C# code to F#. (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs)

```
var consumeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        consumer.Poll(100);
    }
});

consumeTask.Wait();
```

Should it be replaced by `Async` workflow? BTW, is it a way not to use `Poll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more F#-idiomatic way of using Kafka in general, take a look at the [Kafunk](https://github.com/jet/kafunk) library from Jet.com.  It has a nice F# API wrapping the Confluent .NET Kafka library, and in my experience it's also quite performant.

For TPL Tasks, you can use F# Async Workflows in much the same way:

```
let poller = 
    async {
        while true do
            consumer.Poll 100
    }

poller |> Async.Start
```

If you want to use a `Task` inside your Async Workflow, you can use `Async.AwaitTak`, or you can blend them together using a custom workflow, like [this one](http://fssnip.net/7Va).